# R webscraper is not outputting pdf text in one row

Tags: r, web-scraping

I've been web scraping articles in R from the Oxford journals and want to grab the full text of specific articles. All articles have a pdf link to them so I've been trying to pull the pdf link and scrape the entire text onto a csv. The full text should all fit into 1 row however the output in the csv file shows one article of 11 rows. How can I fix this issue?

The code is below:

```
####install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
#for Fulltext to read pdf
####install.packages("pdftools")
library(pdftools)


fullText <- function(parsedDocument){
  endLink <- parsedDocument %>%
    html_node('.article-pdfLink') %>% html_attr('href')
  frontLink <- "https://academic.oup.com"
  #link  of pdf
  pdfLink <- paste(frontLink,endLink,sep = "")
  #extract full text  from pdfLink
  pdfFullText <- pdf_text(pdfLink)
  fulltext <- paste(pdfFullText, sep = "\n")
  return(fulltext)
}
#############################################

#main function with input as parameter year
testFullText <- function(DOIurl){
  parsedDocument <- read_html(DOIurl)
  DNAresearch <- data.frame()
  allData <- data.frame("Full Text" = fullText(parsedDocument), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  DNAresearch <-  rbind(DNAresearch, allData)
  write.csv(DNAresearch, "DNAresearch.csv", row.names = FALSE)
}
testFullText("https://doi.org/10.1093/dnares/dsm026")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your last function, if I understand correctly, you want to take the url and scrape all the text into the a data frame/tibble and then export it to a csv. Here is how you can do it with just 1 article, and you should be able to loop through some links with a little manipulation (apologies if I am misunderstanding):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# read in html link
document_link <- read_html("https://doi.org/10.1093/dnares/dsm026")

# get the text, and put it into a tibble with only 1 row
text_tibble <- document_link %>% 
  html_nodes('.chapter-para') %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  summarize(full_text = paste(value, collapse = " ")) ## this will collpase to 1 row

# now write to csv
## write_csv(text_tibble, file = "")
```